# How to get full home page address of a site collection?

Tags: site-collection, spcontext

When I use `SPContext.Current.Site.Url` it returns "http://servername"

I need the full homepage URL which is "http://servername/SitePages/Home.aspx"

Does anyone know how to get this programmatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

`SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.RootFolder.WelcomePage`

Answer (score 2):

To get full url (absolute), you have to :

```
SPWeb parentWeb=SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb;
string strFullHomePageUrl= parentWeb.Url+ "/"+ parentWeb.RootFolder.WelcomePage;
```

Comment: You can also use `SPUrlUtility` to build the URL: `SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(parentWeb.Url, parentWeb.RootFolder.WelcomePage)`

Answer (score 0):

as an addition, in general, if you are inside a page and you want to get full path you always can use:

```
SPContext.Current.Web.Url + "/" + SPContext.Current.File.Url
```